# How to prevent read.csv from stopping the reading of a file once it hits a corruption symbol?

Tags: r, csv, corruption

I have a csv file that unfortunately has a lengthy amount of corrupted data in the middle of the file (rows 348:68914).  There is however, usable data in the preceding rows as well as the subsequent rows.  When I try to read the file into R, read.csv only reads in the first 347 rows right until a symbol (indicative of the corruption) is encountered.

I have approximately 500 large files, of which 15-20 have this problem.  Since I am trying to automate the processing of all these files, I am trying to avoid manually cleaning out the corrupted data and would like to simply delete the rows once the csv is read into R.

```
> Arb<-read.csv(file = "A0_022916_DataLog.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> str(Arb)
'data.frame':   347 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ Date              : chr  "2000-1-6" "2000-1-6" "2000-1-6" "2000-1-6" ...
 $ Time              : chr  "20:49:35" "20:50:0" "20:51:0" "20:52:0" ...
 $ Outside.Temp.deg.C: chr  "5.84" "5.79" "5.80" "5.84" ...
```

I have tried to troubleshoot this problem by adding specifications to the fileEncoding, quote, and check.names.  I tried latin1, UTF-8, and UTF-16 for the file encoding, but I get an error.

```
> Arb<-read.csv(file = "A0_022916_DataLog.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
+               fileEncoding = "latin1", quote = "", check.names = FALSE)
Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  invalid input found on input connection 'A0_022916_DataLog.csv'
```

Here is a sample of what my data looks like:

```
Date,Time,Outside Temp deg C,Inside Temp deg C,Rain Temp deg C,Wetness Temp deg C,RainCount,Wetness Voltage,Outside Wind Speed,Inside Wind Speed,Heat Percent,Roof Is Open,Roof Vent Is Open,Vent Is Open,Fan Is On,Box Heat Is On,ClkTemp C,High Wind
1/7/2000,2:32:00,5.59,5.9,25.43,16.62,0,0,0,0,0,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,17,FALSE
1/7/2000,2:33:01,5.53,6.22,25.35,16.68,0,0,1.5,0,0,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,16.75,FALSE
1/7/2000,2:34:03,5.63,6.07,25.39,16.74,0,0,1.5,0,0,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,16.5,FALSE
1/7/2000,2:35ø­éüAßj,N²pU(°øKÜÙÀÛª0ÛØ½¹Hõ<`º¦Öópù4)Øváø§ÊîØB!ôË\´-äªý§ÙÐn2P3­ßÈ¶Ý]ëï¾¡V§â¡7Oà~7ãÁô*Êª¼jº¯§ÙLÅQ-ø5sæ{Ás¢qÇËQvn¾QóÞ»t.µÉ·¹EÍ=^KðB÷*óÆÐsMë×Ç]ív¾³Û_ êIy|fcT]ôjËû)©öÈÉ¨Å AíMA×v?Wöà[~ÜP»ëGÖý±c»¤'­¨{,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
¹ÔvM,"B{máü*7L`Ë-MSYúÖqáw¬£VÚsWóú/¨þã]Ck""iØÓtµ7M¡?9ýê'¬AmÏK±Â %DÛyøÐVR`&!ÜÞô'¨oÕ+m[q´fzÃìt@°Æ_v <ërÌ¯^Zm^ä>9Ã]Ò/ÁÅÇD³Q¼ÌÍáÄøûjxW^¢º±éhmyhn÷}nú=HÆ.ðB3^âÆeâLÊa","+gCÌíDÜ{   Ô ò+²¿%ÔÛïYZqL­ð`Ûvô¡XÁÔßø­éüAßj",N²pU(°øKÜÙÀÛª0ÛØ½¹Hõ<`º¦Öópù4)Øváø§ÊîØB!ôË\´-äªý§ÙÐn2P3­ßÈ¶Ý]ëï¾¡V§â¡7Oà~7ãÁô*Êª¼jº¯§ÙLÅQ-ø5sæ{Ás¢qÇËQvn¾QóÞ»t.µÉ·¹EÍ=^KðB÷*óÆÐsMë×Ç]ív¾³Û_ êIy|fcT]ôjËû)©öÈÉ¨Å AíMA×v?Wöà[~ÜP»ëGÖý±c»¤'­¨{,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
¹ÔvM,"B{máü*7L`Ë-MSYúÖqáw¬£VÚsWóú/¨þã]Ck""iØÓtµ7M¡?9ýê'¬AmÏK±Â %DÛyøÐVR`&!ÜÞô'¨oÕ+m[q´fzÃìt@°Æ_v <ërÌ¯^Zm^ä>9Ã]Ò/ÁÅÇD³Q¼ÌÍáÄøûjxW^¢º±éhmyhn÷}nú=HÆ.ðB3^âÆeâLÊa","+gCÌíDÜ{   Ô ò+²¿%ÔÛïYZqL­ð`Ûvô¡XÁÔßø­éüAßj",N²pU(°øKÜÙÀÛª0ÛØ½¹Hõ<`º¦Öópù4)Øváø§ÊîØB!ôË\´-äªý§ÙÐn2P3­ßÈ¶Ý]ëï¾¡V§â¡7Oà~7ãÁô*Êª¼jº¯§ÙLÅQ-ø5sæ{Ás¢qÇËQvn¾QóÞ»t.µÉ·¹EÍ=^KðB÷*óÆÐsMë×Ç]ív¾³Û_ êIy|fcT]ôjËû)©öÈÉ¨Å AíMA×v?Wöà[~ÜP»ëGÖý±c»¤'­¨{,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Thanks in advance for any insights as to how to solve this problem.

Comment: My method for this is to read in up to the corruption, then in a second pass read the content after the corruption using the skip argument. Sadly, this is also a manual practice. You may also look into using the `tryCatch` function.